# C# Chartコントロールをダブルクリックしたときの値を取りたい

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になります。

`Chart` コントロールを使用して、グラフを作成するコードを書いています。

棒グラフの表示まではうまくいき、その棒グラフの中の棒をダブルクリックすることで、
ダブルクリックされたデータのXの要素とYの要素を取得したいと思っています。

他サイト様のサンプルを拝見し、Yの要素の取得まではできたのですが、X軸の要素が
取得できません。

下記にコードを記述します。

```
//ダブルクリックしたとき
private void chart1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result;
    result = this.chart1.HitTest(((MouseEventArgs)e).X, ((MouseEventArgs)e).Y);
    if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
    {
        DataPoint dp = result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex];

        MessageBox.Show(dp.XValue + "," + dp.YValues[0]);
    }
}

//グラフにデータを入れているところ(一部のみ抜粋)
for (int idx = 0; idx < dic.Length; idx++)
{
    Dictionary d = dic[idx];

    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dp = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint();
    dp.SetValueXY(d["year"] + "年" + d["month"] + "月" + d["day"] + "日", int.Parse(d["sheets"]));  //XとYの値を設定
    dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    this.series2.Points.Add(dp);
}
```

`Dictionary`クラスに、年、月、日のデータと、それに該当する値(sheets)があり、
それをグラフに落としています。

取得するところでは、`dp.YValues[0]`で取り出すことはできたのですが、`XValue`では
常に0、そもそも`double`型の返り値でしか拾えません。"2016年4月14日" とかの
文字列、要は表示されているものそのものを拾いたいのですが、どうすれば
良いでしょうか。
それとも、そもそもメソッドの使用方法が間違っているのでしょうか。

ご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X軸ラベルですので[`dp.AxisLabel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.axislabel.aspx)プロパティで参照できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。情けない話です。じゃあ一体XValueとは何なのかって話になりますね。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。